# How to pass a list to @app.route(/<list>)

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to pass a python list in @app.route to define the accepted routes?

I can't find a way to do it :\

Here is what I am trying to do exactly:

```
urilist = ["/log", "/login", "/loginexample"]

@app.route('/<urllist>', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

I would like all the route in the list to redirect to the same function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the parameter from the route to the function, and check if it exists in the list:

```
urilist = ["/log", "/login", "/loginexample"]

@app.route('/<urllist>', methods=['GET'])
def main(urllist):
    if "/{}".format(urllist) in urilist:
       return 'Hello World!'
    return flask.render_template("error.html")#or whatever else you would do if urllist is not in urilist
```

Comment: it is also possible to do if you have an array with value like "/login/log" ? if I try passing a second / in the urilist, it doesn't render anymore and give me 404.